# How to delete some values from a csv column with php

Tags: php, csv

Hello I have this format of data in excel.

```
A              B        C
php           Html     Laravel
mysql         Css      Wordpress
javascript    jquery   Codeigniter
```

I save this as csv and I get comma separated values. I need to delete some items from column C. For example I need to delete Laravel and Codeigniter and the other data are unchanged. How I can do this? I have tried with this code. But this deletes entire row of the specified values.

```
$table = fopen('tech.csv','r');
$temp_table = fopen('table_temp.csv','w');

$id = 'Laravel'; // the name of the column you're looking for

while (($data = fgetcsv($table, 1000)) !== FALSE){
    if(reset($data) == $id){ // this is if you need the first column in a row
        continue;
    }
    fputcsv($temp_table,$data);
}
fclose($table);
fclose($temp_table);
rename('table_temp.csv','tech.csv');
```

So, when I run this it deletes not only 'Laravel' but also the entire row- php, Html, Laravel.

How i can search and delete multiple values from a column without harming other data from the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're telling PHP to `continue` (jumping over the `fputcsv()` line of code) if the row contains Laravel, so it simply won't write any of that row

```
$table = fopen('tech.csv','r');
$temp_table = fopen('table_temp.csv','w');

$names = ['Laravel', 'Codeigniter']; // The values that you're looking to remove
                                     //     (as an array of values)
while (($data = fgetcsv($table, 1000)) !== FALSE){
    $data = array_diff($data, $names);
    fputcsv($temp_table,$data);
}
fclose($table);
fclose($temp_table);
rename('table_temp.csv','tech.csv');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works just fine. I appreciate your help.